# Отменить нажатие клавиши в системе

Tags: python, c++, winapi, pyautogui

Имеется проблема с клавиатурой - залипла (нажалась и не отжимается) клавиша перехода на следующий трек (VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK). Можно ли как-то программно (с помощью языка С++ или Python) отменить это действие? То есть **игнорировать нажатие** этой **клавиши во всех приложениях (во всей операционной системе)**?

Я в С++ разбираюсь плохо, но такого рода программу хотелось написать именно на этом языке (потому что так программа должна получиться более лёгкой), решение на Python меня также устраивает.

На данном этапе написал код, который только определяет нажатые клавиши и выводит их код в консоль:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>


bool is_key_clicked(unsigned short key_code) {
    return GetAsyncKeyState(key_code) & 0x8000;
}

void click_listener() {
    bool run = true;
    while (run) {
        for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        
            if (is_key_clicked(i)) {
                std::cout << "Key " << i << " is pressed." << std::endl;
                if (i == 27) run = false; // 27 is code for "Escape"
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    click_listener();
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**РЕШЕНИЕ**
*Нашёл решение этой проблемы. Скомпилированная программа весит 13Кб и почти не грузит процессор (в отличие от вышеприведённого кода). Работа программы заключается в том, что если нажатая клавиша имеет код 176, то это нажатие будет проигнорировано. Однако во время использования были замечены проскоки (они происходили после нажатия  кнопки Alt, однако было это очень редко).*

```cpp
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>

KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT key;
HHOOK hook;


LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int n_code, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    
    if (n_code >= 0) {
        if (wp == WM_KEYDOWN) {
            keys = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lp);
            std::cout << "\tKey " << key.vkCode << " was pressed" << std::endl;
            if (key.vkCode == 176) {
                CallNextHookEx(hook, n_code, wp, lp);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hook, n_code, wp, lp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    
    if (!(hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0))) std::cout << "Hook doesn't work.";
    MSG m;
    while (true) {
        GetMessage(&m, NULL, 0, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В смысле это у клавиатуры на уровне железа такая проблема? Что-то я сомневаюсь, что это можно программно так починить. Не проще ли починить/поменять клавиатуру?

Comment: Я и не говорил, что хочу программно что-то починить. Я писал, что хочу чтобы операционная система не обращала внимание на то, что нажата клавиша. А на счёт второго вопроса: Прикинь ты сидишь в час ночи пишешь прогу, и у тебя вдруг залипает клава. Что ты теперь комп из-за этого будешь выключать. Или напишешь простинькую программу. (Да, да. Если знать что делать, то проще будет на время написать прогу и пользоваться поломанной клавой дальше.)

Answer (score 3):

Для `Python` есть библиотека [**keyboard**](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) ([документация](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api)).

Можно в несколько строк запретить нажатие с помощью функции `add_hotkey()`

1. Первым аргументом принимается код (`int`) или строковое представление клавиши
2. Вторым бинд функции при нажатии на эту кнопку. Для "заглушки" можно поставить `lambda: None`
3. Нужно указать необязательный параметр `suppress=True` отвечающий за подавление нажатия этой клавиши во всех других приложениях

Код кнопки `-176`, однако, если это не сработает, вы можете определить код с помощью кода в самом низу ответа

```py
import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey(-176, callback=lambda: None, suppress=True)
keyboard.wait()
```

---

Вывод кодов нажатых клавиш:

```py
import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys(e):
    line = ', '.join(str(code) for code in keyboard._pressed_events)
    print('\r' + line + ' '*40, end='')
    
keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

---

*Ну, а вообще, такие проблемы не стоит решать программно. Какой-то костыль получается, как по мне)
Мне кажется, проще купить новую клаву*

Comment: О. Знакомая библиотека. Я ей пользовался. Но проблема в том, что (как я полагаю) она не отменить нажатую кнопку.
И действительно. Я модифицировал Ваш код:
`import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey(176, callback=lambda: None, suppress=True)
def print_pressed_keys(e):
    print(e.name)
    
keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()`
Однако он не позволил проигнорировать нажатие кнопки. Думаю переменная переменна suppress отвечает за то, чтобы событие не распространялось, если оно возникло в самой программе на Python.

Comment: @GreenGras из документации: *`suppress` определяет, должны ли успешные триггеры блокировать отправку ключей в другие программы.*. И по сути это и является отменой нажатия, ведь другие программы эту клавишу не заметят

Comment: Может быть это будет отменой  нажатия, когда оно будет сгенерировано в программе на писанной на Python, ведь скрипт у меня не работал, значит, наверное, нажатие не будет отменено, если оно было сгенерировано в другой программе (например в браузере). Я исправил вопрос. Там ниже я написал решение этой проблемы на языке C++(то есть программа на С++ блокирует нажатие в какой бы программе оно не произошло). Всего хорошего. Спасибо за Ваш ответ.

Comment: @GreenGras а, отлично. В таком случае рекомендую опубликовать решение не в тексте вопроса, а как отдельный ответ и отметить его как решение, чтобы закрыть вопрос